# C++ accurately do action in "every" 100 microsecond without pausing

Tags: c++, loops, scheduling

I writing a program that needs to loop regularly 100 microsecond for one loop. I have found the to loop regularly in a fixed time. But I find a problem when the time for looping is set to be too small.

The following demo code (not complete code) is to:

1. Increment the `count` every 100 microsecond.
2. Show the `count` every 1 second.

The expected result is showing approximately 10000 every second.

But the **result shows about four thousand a second**.

```
void f2(int input)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto displayStart = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    while(true){    //keep looping quickly
      auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
      auto interval = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(now - start);
      if ( interval.count() > input){   //if 100 microsecond do
            count++;
            start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
      }

      auto displayNow = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
      auto displayInterval = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(displayNow - displayStart);
      if ( displayInterval.count() > 1000000){  //if 1 second do
        std::cout<< "1 second count: "<<count<<std::endl;
        count=0;
        displayStart = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

      }

    }

}
```

After that **I think CPU scheduling may be the problem for this**. I have checked the program works normally in every loop . Each iteration takes about 100 microseconds which is accurate. But problem may occur when program/thread is paused and wait for CPU rescheduling.

For example, and lets magnify the value for clearer illustration. The thread paused for 1 second. Normally it will increment for 10000 times. But now, for next iteration it check for >100 microsecond, so count++ and counter is reset as 1 second is passed. For this case, the count incremented only for 1.

With the following code I modified, I can finish 10000 `count++` in a second. **But the problem is those 10000 count is not evenly distributed in one second.** Because this is only the demo program for testing. **The action I actually want is to accurately do action in every 100 microsecond**. But due to the pausing of thread, I still not find the solution to solve this.

```
void f2(int input)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto displayStart = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    while(true){    //keep looping quickly
      auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
      auto interval = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(now - start);
      if ( interval.count() > input){   //if 100 microsecond do
            for(int i=0;i<interval.count()/input;i++){    //modified part
                count++;
            }
            start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

      }


      auto displayNow = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
      auto displayInterval = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(displayNow - displayStart);
      if ( displayInterval.count() > 1000000){  //if 1 second do
        std::cout<< "1 second count: "<<count<<std::endl;
        count=0;
        displayStart = std::chrono::system_clock::now();


      }


    }


}
```

Is there any way like:
eg. make process non pause. Keep it in CPU (not so possible)
to make the counting action in demo program works every 100 microseconds?

Thank you very much

Comment: For this kind of precision, you need [a real-time operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system). General-purpose OS won't let you achieve this - your program may be interrupted at any time by a driver, say. Anyway - what kind of problem are you trying to solve that, you feel, requires performance on the order of 10,000 FPS?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I must use linux for the program. I am writing a software switch that need to *0.08 for every 100 microsecond for the counter for computing some data for other purpose. (computing congestion data for every port)

Comment: You'll have to find another way to compute that data, I'm afraid. If you explain what actual problem you are trying to solve, rather than your attempted solution (that you can't get to work anyway), you might get some help. See also: [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @RaymondMa Do you need to do it every 100 ms?  If it is 200 ms, would *.08 * .08 not work?  Could you record all activity with timestamps and decay them continuously?

Comment: @RaymondMa You might want to look into the real time linux options. Some of them claim to be suitable for hard real time.

Comment: @Yakk As I am writing software switch that consider the congestion in the ports. The simple but not complete concept is  1. There is a thread to count++ when packet goes out from port i. 2.I need to reduce the counter with a regular time quickly. It is studied that I should multiply a value in 100 microseconds to keep the congestion data fresh.

Comment: @Yakk eg. 5 packets goes out in first 100 μs, 2 packet goes out in second 100 μs. Now, I expect to get 5*.08 + 2*.08 , instead of 7*.08*.08

Comment: I will try studying the real time OS/ options, thank you very much.

Comment: It might be possible to do this on Linux but it'll have to be very heavily tuned OS to make sure your thread doesn't get stopped longer than tolerable (probably with -rt patched kernel). Maybe also with DPDK or something similar to get kernel out of the way when working with network.

Answer (score 0):

Have N buckets, where N is large enough that scheduling delay won't be a problem.

Keep track of the last time your decay code ran.

When a new packet "goes out", put it in a bucket based on the last time your decay code ran (if less than 100 ms, bucket 0, if 200 ms, bucket 1, etc).

When your decay code runs, calculate the current value after decaying everything properly and update the timestamp.

Note that contention (the thread updating and the thread decaying) will remain a problem.  You can fix this to some extent with double or triple buffering of the counters, atomic flags and pointers, and busy-loops in the non-performance-sensitive code (say, the decay code).

Alternatively, instead of recording counts, record time stamps.  Consume the buffer of time stamps, doing decay at that point.  Similar issues involving size of buffer and multiple threads remain, with similar solutions.

Alternatively, do the decay math in the code that is doing the counting.